# C++ - difference between first two elements

Tags: c++, set

I've recently began to work with `C++ std::sets`, so there is a question I did not find answer to in Google.

I have a `std::set` of some `int` values (e.g., let it be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`). The task is to calculate difference between two first elements. Is it possible to do with C++?

I'm using data structure `std::set`; And I know that first element can be got like that:

> int diff = *arSeq.begin();

Where `arSeq` is mentioned `set`.

Is there any way to get the second element?

Comment: You should consult the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to see what element access options you have.

Comment: You mean sets in the mathematical sense? Because those are not ordered and there's no "first" element. If you are talking about `std::set` in the data structure sense, clarify you post.

Comment: Isn't the definition of a set that there is no defined order of elements? So please define "first two".

Comment: Ok, iI'll edit now

Comment: @Yunnosch It says `std::set` in the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza True. And the spec for a std::set says "Associative:
Elements in associative containers are referenced by their key and not by their absolute position in the container." Which means that you can use the iterator to get the first in whatever storage representation, but there is no defined correspondence to any order outside of that.

Comment: @Yunnosch, also true. But the DO have specified order. There are sorted in ascending order, as far as I know.

Comment: @Yunnosch `std::set` has a very well specified ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Access the first element via the [std::set::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin) iterator and the next one using the [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto result = *s.begin() - *std::next(s.begin());
    std::cout << result;
}
```

Please note that you will again get the same result of `-1` even if you defined your set as:

```
std::set<int> s = { 5, 3, 1, 4, 2 };
```

because the [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a container that:

> contains a sorted set of unique objects...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

    long long int diff = 0;

    if (not (s.size() < 2))
    {
        auto first = s.begin();
        auto second = std::next(first);

        diff = *first < *second ? ( long long int )*second - *first : ( long long int )*first - *second;
    }

    std::cout << "difference = " << diff << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from your entire post my eyes jumped to `if (not (...` and just I was about to comment that this is a `c++` question I remembered: oh yeah... in `C++` `not` is a keyword ... now I am sad again ...

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by first two elements. First two element inserted? then its not possible.
Set elements are sorted with given comparator. By default primitive elements are sorted in ascending order. See the output of following program.

```
// set::begin/end
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include<functional>

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  std::set<int, std::greater<int>> myset (myints,myints+5);

  auto first = myset.begin();
  auto second = std::next(first);

  std::cout <<*first<< ", " <<*second<<"\n";

  return 0;
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: The working answer has already been given. Thank you for your reply anyway